# Problem with scrolling down with Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've tried so far unsuccessfully to scroll down a website with Python/Selenium. This is the website I need to scroll down:

https://www.fiercepharma.com/keyword/drug-prices

The only result I'm able to reach is to scroll down to the middle of the page, which is half way what I need: I need to reach and click on the "**See more articles**" button at the bottom of the page.

I've tried many things. I've tried to locate button's elements with the XPath method but it is as if locating these elements are impossible when the scroll down stops at the middle of the page.

Could you me help by seeing what is wrong with my piece of code?

```
page_elements = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="section-front-content-well"\]/div/div\[7\]/div\[1\]/span').click()
```

```
page_elements = driver.execute_script("arguments\[0\].scrollIntoView();", driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//\*\[@id="section-front-content-well"\]/div/div\[7\]/div\[1\]/span').click())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.execute_script('return document.title')
```

Also you need to handle cookies alert before click on 'See more article' button

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.fiercepharma.com/keyword/drug-prices')
driver.maximize_window()
# set explicit wait of 20 seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Click on X cookies button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='Continue Browsing']"))).click()

# Wait for See more articles to be clickable and click on it
see_more_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='See more articles']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", see_more_btn)
```